# Generate combinations of a list of strings without repetitions and anchor element

Tags: python, combinations, permutation

I have a list which looks as follows:

```
x = [ 'foo', 'bar', 'alpha' ]
```

The output should be like follows. So 'foo' needs to be always present in the output

```
[
 ['foo'],
 ['foo', 'bar']
 ['foo','alpha']
 ['foo','bar','alpha']
]
```

I have looked at the **itertools.permutations** and **itertools.combinations** but both doesn't seem to work with this use-case as they consider the values to be unique by location not by value in an array.

Comment: So, handle `foo` separately.  Remove it from the last, and run normal permutations on what remains.

Comment: @Roberts itertools.permutations([‘bar’, ‘alpha’]) gives me two outputs  [‘bar’, ‘alpha’],[‘alpha’,’bar’] but I also need the single instances like [‘bar’] and [‘alpha’] to be able to multiple with ‘foo’. How to get all the 4 outputs ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `combinations` on `x[1:]`, varying the parameter `r`:

```py
import itertools

x = ['foo', 'bar', 'alpha']

output = []
for r in range(len(x)):
    output += [['foo'] + list(a) for a in itertools.combinations(x[1:], r)] # attach 'foo' to each item

print(output) # [['foo'], ['foo', 'bar'], ['foo', 'alpha'], ['foo', 'bar', 'alpha']]
```

In python 3.5+, you can use [unpacking](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/) in the loop to enhance readability:

```py
    output += [['foo', *a] for a in itertools.combinations(x[1:], r)]
```

Comment: Nice way to use `itertools.combinations`. Well done!